# Plot 5 plots at the same time using par() and for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

Trying to plot 5 t-SNE plots at the same time, instead of repeating the same code 5 times.
Each time I just change the **vector**. So this is what I'm trying to do:

```
mylst = list(totaldata$dataset,totaldata$Response,totaldata$CR,totaldata$RECIST, totaldata$Cancer_Type)

for(i in 1:length(mylst)) {
  par(mfcol = c(3, 3))
  tsne = Rtsne(t(scores.batch))
  tsnetotal <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[,1], y = tsne$Y[,2], col = as.factor(mylst[i]))
  ggplot(tsnetotal) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color = col), size = 3)+ theme_classic() +  xlab("t-SNE 1") + 
  ylab("t-SNE 2") + scale_colour_manual(breaks=colmapping$Var1, values=colmapping$mycolors) + title(main= paste("plot of ", mylst[i]))
  
}
```

As you can see, I want to plot a t-SNE plot based on each vector found in `mylst`. Previously, this is what the code looked like and I'm trying to make it cleaner:

```
tsne = Rtsne(t(scores.batch))
tsnetotal <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[,1], y = tsne$Y[,2], col = as.factor(totaldata$dataset))
ggplot(tsnetotal) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color = col), size = 3)+ theme_classic() +  xlab("t-SNE 1") + 
  ylab("t-SNE 2") + scale_colour_manual(breaks=colmapping$Var1, values=colmapping$mycolors)


tsnetotal.2 <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[,1], y = tsne$Y[,2], col = as.factor(totaldata$Response))
ggplot(tsnetotal.2) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=col))+theme_classic() +  xlab("t-SNE 1") + ylab("t-SNE 2")


tsnetotal.3 <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[,1], y = tsne$Y[,2], col = as.factor(totaldata$CR))
ggplot(tsnetotal.3) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=col), size = 3)+theme_classic() + xlab('t-SNE 1')+ylab('t-SNE 2') + theme_gray()

tsnetotal.4 <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[,1], y = tsne$Y[,2], col = totaldata$RECIST)
ggplot(tsnetotal.4) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=col, size = 3))+theme_classic() + xlab('tSNE 1')+ylab('tSNE 2') 


tsne.5 = Rtsne(t(scores.batch))
tsnetotal.5 <- data.frame(x = tsne.5$Y[,1], y = tsne.5$Y[,2], col = as.factor(totaldata$Cancer_Type))
ggplot(tsnetotal.5) + geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color=col),size = 4)+theme_classic() + xlab('t-SNE 1')+ylab('t-SNE 2') +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks=colmappingMore$Var1, values=colmappingMore$mycolorsMore) +  theme_gray()
```

Comment: And what is the result of your attempt? Any errors or undesired results? `par` is for base R graphics. Consider [`gridExtra`](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/RProgDA/the-grid-package.html#the-gridextra-package) for plotting multiple `ggplot`s.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I would do something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_data_list_grid <- function(data_list){
  map(data_list,
      \(d) {
        title <- paste0("cyl: ", d$cyl[1])
        
        ggplot(d, aes(hp, mpg))+
          geom_point()+
          ggtitle(title)
        }) |>
    (\(pl) cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = pl))()
}

mtcar_dat <- group_split(mtcars, cyl)

plot_data_list_grid(mtcar_dat)
```

[image]

Because I do not have your data, I cannot test the approach, but I would expect your code to look something like:

```r
mylst = list(totaldata$dataset,totaldata$Response,totaldata$CR,totaldata$RECIST,totaldata$Cancer_Type)
tsne = Rtsne(t(scores.batch))

plot_data_list_grid <- function(data_list){
  map(data_list,
      \(d) {
        tsnetotal <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[,1], y = tsne$Y[,2], col = as.factor(d))
        title = paste("plot of ", d)
        
        ggplot(tsnetotal) + 
          geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, color = col), size = 3)+ 
          theme_classic() +
          xlab("t-SNE 1") + 
          ylab("t-SNE 2") + 
          scale_colour_manual(breaks=colmapping$Var1, values=colmapping$mycolors)+
          ggtitle(title)
        }) |>
    (\(pl) cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = pl))()
}

plot_data_list_grid(mylst)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:  `Insufficient values in manual scale. 19 needed but only 17 provided` `Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred`

Comment: that's probably because you wrote `scale_colour_manual(breaks=colmapping$Var1, values=colmapping$mycolors)` in your example. you likely give not enough colors. you didn't provide info on `colmapping`, so I don't know its structure.

Comment: Yes my bad, I have two color vectors, one of them contains 17 colors, and the second has 19 colors. This is because one of the t-SNE plots has 17 different values, and another plot has 19 values. `totaldata$dataset` has 17 values, and `totaldata$Cancer_Type` has 19 values.. The rest don't matter they have 4 or 5 values so the colors won't be a problem. I made these color vectors because with high values number like 19 the colors will look the same and it's hard to distinguish which is which, so I have to pick them manually.